# Using write.xlsx in R, how to write in a Specific Row or column in excel file

Tags: r

I am using R and I need to write the results in excel file. For this I am using "xlsx" package in R. I have the following questions:

1) Please can you tell me, how to write in a specific cell of excel file? , ie, I want to write in "B10" cell of my excel sheet

2) How to write in the pre-defined range (for e.g "B10:H20")

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is how you set up your initial data. Here's one solution you could use. You haven't included any example data, so I've just used the 2 cell references you've listed.

```
library(xlsx) #load the package
# we'll assume your spreadsheet will be 20 rows & 8 columns
m <- (matrix('',nrow = 20,ncol = 8)) # '' removes NA from your final spreadsheet
# place values in specific cells 
m[10,2] <- c("B10") # as B10 is in row 10 and column 2
m[20,8] <- c("H20")
# export as xlsx
write.xlsx(x = m, file = "your.excelfile.xlsx",sheetName = "test", row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 7):

To insert into B10:H20 range of an existing file:

```
library(xlsx)
# load file contents
file <- "yourfilename.xlsx"
wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
sheet <- sheets[[1]]  # or another
# data to put into B10:H20 range
data <- matrix(runif(7*11), nrow=11, ncol=7)
# modify contents
addDataFrame(data, sheet, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE,
    startRow = 10, startColumn = 2)
# save to disk
saveWorkbook(wb, file)
```

Probably not the most elegant way, but can be a starting point for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. It works fine.