# Exporting multiple R data frames to a single Excel sheet

Tags: r, export-to-excel, xlsx, xlconnect

I would like to export multiple data frames from `R` to a single `Excel` sheet. By using the following code:

```
write.xlsx(DF1, file="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet1", 
       col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE)

write.xlsx(DF2, file="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet2", 
       col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=TRUE)
```

I can export two data frames to a single excel workbook, but in two separate sheets. I would like to export them in a single sheet, andif possible, to determine the specific cells that these data frames will be placed in.

Any suggestions more than welcome.

Comment: What do `DF1` and `DF2` look like?  If they have the same columns you could `rbind(DF1, DF2)` and then export, if they have the same rows you could `cbind(DF1, DF2)` and then export.

Comment: @Hackerman Error in .jcall(wb, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;", "createSheet",  : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name

Comment: @slackline cbind works but the output is not really what I want. I have two tables equal number or rows (same grouping variable) and different number of columns. And I would like them to appear next to each other but with some space (few columns)  between them.

Comment: @Hackerman unfortunately Andre Elrico  is right. I tried the same thing that you suggested before I write this post, but it is not possible.

Comment: @Ioannis Add empty columns to the table you wish to be on the left before you `cbind(DF1, DF2)`, something like `DF1$dummy <- ""`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a ready to use answer but this should get you to your target. It would be a mess to write it into a comment.

1. Create the combined df with the tools of R
2. Write df to excel

a few notes to point 1.:

vertical offset the second df from the first by using `Reduce(rbind,c(list(mtcars),rep(list(NA),3)))` for a 3 cell offset for e.g.

rbind the colnames to your df `rbind(names(mtcars),mtcars)`

use numbers as colnames for so you will not have a problem rbinding different df with different variables. `names(mtcars) <- seq_along(mtcars)`

To point 2.:

Since your colnames are numbers now make sure you have your colnames set as `FALSE`.

Hope this helps and you can get your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Following most of your suggestions I realized that by using cbind.data.frame I get an output which is not optimal, but the amount of time that I need to restructure the data in EXCEL is really insignificant. So, I will proceed with this for the time being.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I'll provide my input here:

[Using write.xlsx in R, how to write in a Specific Row or column in excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632137/using-write-xlsx-in-r-how-to-write-in-a-specific-row-or-column-in-excel-file)

In that link it is suggested to organize your data in a single data frame to then write that into the excel sheet. You should have a look at that.

as slackline suggested, this is quite easy if your columns or rows are the same, using his suggested methods

Edit: To add spaces in between, just insert empty columns in between before writing